# How to start working on python GUI .

Tags: wxpython

I need to develop a software in 30 days with features like inputting a data in a grid and then presenting with a graph and some basic calculations? Which platform is the best and where to start from? Please help me out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question is off-topic here because it's against site policy for questions to be primarily asking for opinions, and to ask for tool or resource recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

If you're new to Python and you have a full four weeks to get up to speed, you might like the Tkinter interface as it's included with Python and gives you plenty of user controls out of the box. See this link for a good intro:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

And seeing as you seem to want to cover a fair few bases, you could do a lot worse than pick up a good book on Tkinter to take you from A to Z rather than grubbing around on the net for answers to specific q's. This is a good title on the UK version of Amazon.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Modern-Tkinter-Busy-Python-Developers-ebook/dp/B0071QDNLO

The book assumes a basic knowledge of Python. For that you can rely on the net, though. Python  documentation is nearly always first-rate.